# Hamiltonian monte carlo

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

Can someone explain the main idea behind Hamiltonian Monte Carlo methods and in which cases they will yield better results than Markov Chain Monte Carlo methods ?

Comment: This is covered extensively in the Stan documentation.

Comment: @General Abrial: but aren't all questions here covered in one or other paper or book or documentation?

Comment: Yeah. And by pointing you to the resource, I've provided an answer.

Comment: @General Abrial: well I wouldn't call it an answer, you gave me a name and I hope that if I find the document that I will also find the answer in it. :-)

Comment: https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/releases/download/v2.9.0/stan-reference-2.9.0.pdf may be discovered by going to www.google.com and typing "stan documentation."

Comment: Also: http://www.mcmchandbook.net/HandbookChapter5.pdf

Comment: The question is not well posed, since Hamiltonian Monte Carlo is an example of a Markov Chain Monte Carlo method.

Comment: @aripakman: then I will be delighted if you can explain me in what sense the HMC is a particular case of a general case that is MCMC.

Comment: In the following sense: when the Hamiltonian equations of motion can be integrated, the transition kernel satisfies detailed balance. When they cannot be integrated, the final values of the position and momentum are used in a Metropolis-Hastings proposal.

Comment: @aripakman: do you have a good reference that explains under which conditions these Hamiltonian dynamics define a Markov chain that converges to a steady state distribution that is my posterior ?

Comment: Sure, this is an good review http://www.mcmchandbook.net/HandbookChapter5.pdf

Comment: @aripakman: Thx, this is what I was searching for, if you make an answer out of it then I can vote for it and make it the best answer.

Comment: You did notice, that Zen linked you to exactly the same URL on May 28th already?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the most up-to-date source on Hamiltonian Monte Carlo, its practical applications and comparison to other MCMC methods is this 2017-dated [review paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02434.pdf) by Betancourt:

> The ultimate challenge in estimating probabilistic expectations is quantifying the typical set of the target distribution, a set which concentrates near a complex surface in parameter space. Hamiltonian Monte Carlo generates coherent exploration of smooth target distributions by exploiting the geometry of the typical set. This effective exploration yields not only better computational efficiency than other Markov chain Monte Carlo algorithms, but also stronger guarantees on the validity of the resulting estimators. Moreover, careful analysis
>   of this geometry facilitates principled strategies for automatically constructing optimal implementations of the method, allowing users to focus their expertise into building better models instead of wrestling with the frustrations of statistical computation. As a result, Hamiltonian  Monte Carlo is uniquely suited to tackling the most challenging problems at the frontiers of applied statistics, as demonstrated by the huge success of tools like [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/) (Stan Development Team, 2017).

Comment: This is a wee bit overselling the approach!

Answer (score 4):

Hamiltonian Monte Carlo ([HMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_Monte_Carlo)), originally called Hybrid Monte Carlo, is a form of Markov Chain Monte Carlo with a momentum term and corrections.

The "Hamiltonian" refers to Hamiltonian mechanics.

The use-case is stochastically (randomly) exploring high dimensions for numeric integration over a probability space.

### Contrast with MCMC

Plain/vanilla Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) uses only the last state to determine the next state. That means that you are as likely to go forward as you are to go back over space you have already explored.

MCMC also is likely to drift outside of the primary area of interest in high dimensional spaces as well.

This makes MCMC very inefficient for the purposes of numeric integration over a multidimensional probability space.

#### How HMC handles these issues

By adding in a momentum term, HMC makes the exploration of the probability space more efficient, as you are now more likely to make forward progress with each step through your probability space.

HMC also uses [Metropolis-Hastings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) corrections to ensure it stays in and explores the region of greater probability.

In writing up this answer, I found [this presentation on HMC to be quite illuminating.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnNdhsm0rJQ)